# How to change the banner name on organization news articles

Tags: sharepoint-online-powershell

I've enabled two communication sites as organization news sites for our SharePoint online tenant, one for CEO news and one for Firmwide news, but rather having the name of the organization news site in the banner for a news article authored in that site e.g. CEO, it's got our tenant home site name in the banner. I'm not sure what I've done wrong here. I'm wondering if it's to do with one of the common parameters in the Powershell script on Microsoft's syntax page:  [syntax link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/set-spoorgnewssite?view=sharepoint-ps). If so, I can't find what these parameters could be. Has anyone got this working, please?